# Switching b/w versions of PHP on a NginX + PHP-FPM Setup

Tags: php, nginx, php5, php-fpm

On Apache you could easily configure it through an htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
Action    php-fcgi    /fcgi-bin/phpcgi-starter-5.3
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
Action    php-fcgi    /fcgi-bin/phpcgi-starter-5.4
</IfModule>
```

Is there something similar for Nginx + PHP-FPM?

Answer (score 0):

Just run each version of php-fpm on a different port (or socket) and configure the appropriate port in your `fastcgi_pass` parameter in your nginx `server` block. For instance, you might have 5.3 run on port 9000 and 5.4 run on port 9001.

Comment: but how will php-fpm know which version of PHP to use?

Comment: You specify which one to connect to in your nginx configuration, exactly as I already said.

Comment: But how do I make 5.3 and 5.4 run on a specific port?

Comment: You edit the pool configuration and set the `listen` address appropriately.